# Using du to get size of specific sub directories

Tags: linux, bash, du

I'm trying to write a script to summarise a bunch of folders. So I have the following structure:

```
monitor/abc_123 1G
monitor/abc_213 1G 
monitor/abc_111 2G
monitor/bbc_123 2.5G
```

What I need is to issue a command (using du I presume) to summarise the directories prefixed with "abc_"

I've tried the following:

```
du -sh abc*
```

... but this just gives me a summary for each folder. I need the script to generate the total size of all three directories in this example.

Thanks in advance

Comment: the summary **is** the total size of a directory and all of its subdirectories and files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
du -ch abc_* | tail -n 1
```

That should produce a grand total.

Comment: Whoa that was quick - kudos! So simple, yet that does exactly what I need. Thanks very much.